# Move the search dropdown menu to appear above the search input box in sharepoint 2010

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Basically by default the search dropdown menu appears on the left of the search box in an additional , i want it to appear above the search input field, is there built in functionality on the control to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to change the layout of the search box. As it is a delegate control there isn't much you can change either - but what I did in a recent customization project:

Use Javascript to pull out the scopes dropdown and just place it somewhere else. The dropdown aswell as the input box, both sit within a table in the following structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><select ...><!--scopes dropdown--></td>
            <td><input ...><!--search box --></td>
            <td><input ...><!--search button --></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With either jQuery or just regular Javascript you could get the `innerHTML` of the scope dropdown `td` and just place it anywhere else on the page.

Comment: Thanks, Its pretty much what i ended up doing in the beginning, I just didn't really want to go down that route if there was a built method.